# How to improve a cumbersome comparison of 2 objects' fields

Tags: java, reflection

We have a program that compares thousands of pairs of `Students` by checking each field of the Student and counting the diffs:

```
class Student{

   String name;
   String address;
   String biologyCourse;
    .....
   // about 100 other fields
}
```

And the counter POJO class:

```
class Counters{
  long bothStudentsHaveName;
  long onlyLeftHasName;
  long onlyRightHasName;

   ......
  // number of fields in Student * 3 (both, only left, only right)
}
```

Our compare function accepts 2 students plus the counters object and needs to scan the fields and update the relevant counters:

```
    public void compareStudents(Student left, Student right, Counters counters){

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(left.name) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(right.name) ){
            counters.bothStudentsHaveName++;
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(left.name) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(right.name)){
            counters.onlyRightHasName++;
        } else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(left.name) && StringUtils.isEmpty(right.name))){
            counters.onlyLeftHasName++;
        }

     /// and now??
}
```

At this point, we can add 100s more triplets of `if/else` like the above - but we believe there should be a much easier way to do that.

`Reflection` can be an option or maybe X dimensions arrays, but can we somehow write the code so the comparison and counting will be much more generic?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I mean why are you calculating the differences between each of the fields?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz because this is the business need

Comment: Why are these counters `long`? If they are meant to be incremented only once? In my opinion, `boolean` is a more realistic choice here.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz the counters are long as we will compare many students and not just 2. I'll update the question

Comment: I have answered your question. Let me know whether it's working or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved your problem with one single loop. But here I'm assuming that naming convention for all the fields will be the same as described in your question. Here I am dynamically accessing the `Student` fields and updating `Counter` fields accordingly. Here is the complete solution:

**Solution Class:**

```
public class Solution {
    public void compareStudents(Student left, Student right, Counter counter) throws Exception {
        for (Field field : Student.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object leftValue = field.get(left);
            Object rightValue = field.get(right);

            String fieldName = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);

            if(leftValue != null && rightValue != null) {
                Field counterField = Counter.class.getDeclaredField("bothStudentsHave" + fieldName);
                counterField.set(counter, (long) counterField.get(counter) + 1);
            } else if (leftValue != null) {
                Field counterField = Counter.class.getDeclaredField("onlyLeftHas" + fieldName);
                counterField.set(counter, (long) counterField.get(counter) + 1);
            } else if (rightValue != null) {
                Field counterField = Counter.class.getDeclaredField("onlyRightHas" + fieldName);
                counterField.set(counter, (long) counterField.get(counter) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Student Class:**

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String address;
    String biologyCourse;
}
```

**Counter Class:**

```
class Counter {
    // name
    long bothStudentsHaveName;
    long onlyLeftHasName;
    long onlyRightHasName;
    // address
    long bothStudentsHaveAddress;
    long onlyLeftHasAddress;
    long onlyRightHasAddress;
    // biologyCourse
    long bothStudentsHaveBiologyCourse;
    long onlyLeftHasBiologyCourse;
    long onlyRightHasBiologyCourse;
    // ... and so on


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Counter{" + "\n" +
                "\tbothStudentsHaveName = " + bothStudentsHaveName + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyLeftHasName = " + onlyLeftHasName + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyRightHasName = " + onlyRightHasName + "\n" +
                "\t, bothStudentsHaveAddress = " + bothStudentsHaveAddress + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyLeftHasAddress = " + onlyLeftHasAddress + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyRightHasAddress = " + onlyRightHasAddress + "\n" +
                "\t, bothStudentsHaveBiologyCourse = " + bothStudentsHaveBiologyCourse + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyLeftHasBiologyCourse = " + onlyLeftHasBiologyCourse + "\n" +
                "\t, onlyRightHasBiologyCourse = " + onlyRightHasBiologyCourse + "\n" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Tester Class:**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Creating Dummy Variables
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.name = "Test";
        student1.biologyCourse = "Yes";
        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.name = "Test1";
        student2.address = "abc street";
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        // Comparing Students
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.compareStudents(student1, student2, counter);

        // Printing Counter
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> ```
> Counter{
>   bothStudentsHaveName = 1
>   , onlyLeftHasName = 0
>   , onlyRightHasName = 0
>   , bothStudentsHaveAddress = 0
>   , onlyLeftHasAddress = 0
>   , onlyRightHasAddress = 1
>   , bothStudentsHaveBiologyCourse = 0
>   , onlyLeftHasBiologyCourse = 1
>   , onlyRightHasBiologyCourse = 0
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep repreating the same basic pattern of fields, then consider extracting that into a class. For example introduce a `FieldComparison` class that looks a little like this:

```
public class FieldComparisonCounter {
  public int bothHave;
  public int onlyLeftHas;
  public int onlyRightHas;

  // constructor, getters, setters left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

Then have a `Map<String,FieldComparisonCounter> counters` somewhere and a method like this:

```
public void compareField(String fieldName, String leftValue, String rightValue) {
  FieldComparisonCounter counter = counters.get(fieldName);
  if (counter == null) {
    counter = new FieldComparisonCounter();
    counters.put(fieldName, counter);
  }
  boolean leftHas = !StringUtils.isEmpty(leftValue);
  boolean rightHas = !StringUtils.isEmpty(rightValue);
  if (leftHas && rightHas) {
    counter.bothHave++;
  } else if (leftHas) {
    counter.onlyLeftHas++;
  } else if (rightHas) {
    counter.onlyRightHas++;
  }
}
```

Then adding a new field comparison is as simple as calling

```
compareField("name", left.name, right.name);
```